# How can I generalize this getVisibleElement function?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using the selenium javascript webdriver, and I'd like to make a general 'getVisibleElement' function. I saw this version in the webdriver source code:

```
  var link = driver.findElement(firstVisibleLink);

  function firstVisibleLink(driver) {
    var links = driver.findElements(By.tagName('a'));
    return webdriver.promise.filter(links, function(link) {
      return links.isDisplayed();
    }).then(function(visibleLinks) {
      return visibleLinks[0];
    });
  }
```

Is there a way that I can generalize this such that I can pass in any css selector as parameter and get just the first visible version of it? I've been having issues with 'invalid locator' and 'undefined is not a function' errors the ways i have been trying.

Page:

```
var webdriverUtils = require('../../utils/extendWebdriver_utils');
    function contactCardPage(){
        var elements = Object.create({}, {
            viewToggle: { get: function(){
                return webdriverUtils.getFirstVisibleElement('[name="viewToggle"]');
            }
        }

        this.toggleView = function(){
            return elements.viewToggle.click();
        }
    });
module.exports = new contactCardPage();
```

WebdriverUtils:

```
function webdriverUtils(){
    this.getFirstVisibleElement = function(selectorString){
        var elements = session.driver.findElements(webdriver.By.css(selectorString));

        return webdriver.promise.filter(elements, function(el) {
            return el.isDisplayed();
        }).then(function(visibleElement) {
                return visibleElement[0];
        });
    }
});
module.exports = new webdriverUtils();
```

Spec:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var contactCardPage = require('../../pageObjects/contactCardPage.js');
describe('Contacts', function () {
    it('Can be expanded', function(done){
        contactCardPage.toggleView().then(function(){
            //Expect here for making sure expanded elements are now displayed
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Currently this gives me an 'Invalid Locator' error.

Is there any way to pass in a selector and get just the visible elements this way?